# EntityFramework code first: Set order of fields

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I am using EntityFramework with the "Code first" approach with migrations.

I have successfully generated tables from my models, but the columns are being added in an alphabetical order rather than the order inside my model.

I have tried this:

```
[Key, Column(Order=0)]
public int MyFirstKeyProperty { get; set; }

[Column(Order=1)]
public int MySecondKeyProperty { get; set; }
```

But that doesn't seem to be working.

How can I manually set the order of the fields in the database?

I am using ASP.NET Core and EF Core (SqlServer) v1.1.0.

Comment: It was supposed to be fixed in EF Core 2.1.0, but it was punted out of the release and is still OPEN and in Backlog...  Bummer.  https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11314

Comment: @Jess Just to be clear, that's a different issue.  Ordering the columns based on the property order is not what the OP asked about.  That actually shipped (though with the caveats mentioned in that Issue you referenced) in v2.1; see issue #2272.  What the OP asked about is using the ColumnAttribute's Order property, which still won't ship in v3.0, unfortunately.  The two issues are easily confused; that's still useful into you posted, though!

Comment: EF Core 5.0.6 - tried it out, but column ordering is still not working (code first).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Currently ordering columns by class property is not implemented. 
Here's the long discussion about column ordering. [Column ordering #2272](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2272)

**[Update as of 07/12/2017](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2272)**

> This issue is in the Backlog milestone. This means that it is not
>   going to happen for the 2.0 release. We will re-assess the backlog
>   following the 2.0 release and consider this item at that time.

**[Update as of 06/10/2019](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10059)**

Issue 2272 shipped with EF Core v2.1 and matches the order of the columns in the generated table to the order of the properties in the class.  However, as @lloyd-conrade mentioned, this is only useful for initial creation

A new issue, #10059, has been created to track the possible implementation of respecting the Column attribute's Order property.

> If the implementation of #2272 is insufficient for you and specifying something 
>   like [Column(Order = 1)] would help, please vote for this issue and add details 
>   about your scenario (if not already listed) below.

Note the "Punted for 3.0" label was added on May 10th, 2019, which is to say it will **not** ship in EF Core 3.0.

Comment: Quite disappointing, especially *There is no plan to change this in any of the currently scheduled releases. The correct thing to do it you don't like the column order is to edit the generated migration file and move the order around as desired.* +1 for the answer though.

Comment: Thanks guys! Manually editing the `CreateTable` call did the trick. Shame it's not supported by EF Core yet, but hopefully it will be.

Comment: Any tips on what to do when in some next migrations a new column is introduced that should be the let's say second column in the table?

Comment: While column ordering is as per their definition in the class, on first migration as others have noted, if your class inherits properties, then the properties of the child class occur first followed by those in the parent class. I would have thought it to be parent first, as in normal inheritance, the parent's properties are initialized before the child's.

Answer (score 7):

Update: In EF Core 2.1, for the initial migration at least, columns are added to tables in the order in which the relevant properties are declared in their respective classes, rather than in alphabetical order. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1#better-column-ordering-in-initial-migration).  But note that any subsequent Entity Framework migrations performed on the same tables won't change the column order of the columns created earlier.

Answer (score 4):

As of Entity Framework Core 6 you can specify the column order with an annotation:

```
[Column(Order = 1)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt#column-order

Answer (score 1):

At this moment **EF core doesn't support it**.But there is a workaround for that.That is, you can explicitly specify SQL on your migration operation.

Instead of using the `CreateTable` method in your migrations, you need to explicitly write the SQL as shown below.There you can give the order as you wish.

```
migrationBuilder.Sql("CREATE TABLE Properties(
   MyFirstKeyProperty   INT   NOT NULL,
   MySecondKeyProperty int    NOT NULL,
   AGE  INT   NOT NULL,
   ......
   ......   
   PRIMARY KEY (MyFirstKeyProperty)
)");
```

You can read about the [**rowanmiller's commnet here about how to sort out that issue just for now**](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2272#issuecomment-158552806)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this solution to add support for explicit column ordering to your project: https://github.com/premchandrasingh/EFCoreColumnOrder. This solution adds the HasColumnOrder extension method. There is an example of use in the Sample folder. Do not forget to replace the corresponding services in your DbContext.

Comment: And what does that do with new columns added to an existing table?

Comment: If you specify the ordinal number of a column explicitly using the HasColumnOrder extension method, then the column will be placed in the correct place.

Comment: That would trigger a table rebuild. I'm not sure if this will really happen and if it happens it would be highly undesirable. Did you test this scenario?

Comment: This solution allows you to specify an explicit column order only when creating a table (CreateTable method in EF migration). And of course this solution does not rebuild the table if the table already exists.

Answer (score 1):

the order of the columns you mention is used to specify the order of the columns a compound foreign key, as it is in the case of some tables that have two or more fields as foreign key that refer to other tables, in that case you can use Column (Order = n)