# EntityHistory fails for owned type with reference to other entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate, abp

Here is my model:

```
public class Investment : FullAuditedEntity<Guid>
{
    public string some_property { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address : ValueObject<Address>
{
    [ForeignKey("CountryId")]
    public Country Country { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("StateId")]
    public State State { get; set; }
    public string StateId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DistrictId")]
    public District District { get; set; }
    public string DistrictId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CommuneId")]
    public Commune Commune { get; set; }
    public string CommuneId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to create new investment and save to DB, ABP tries to identify whether it should store entity changes in history tables, but it crashes when trying to identify owner (investment) for owned entity (address). 
This is because ABP always take first foreignkey (assuming it's relation to owner entity), but in my case the first foreignkey is relationship to some other entity, thus there is no "PrincipalToDependent" value and save action is terminated:

[image]
[image]

Is there any workaround for this or we cannot have references stored in owned entity type?

Comment: Please create an issue on [aspnetboilerplate](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate) repo. As for workaround, if the alphabetical order is actually the column order, then [EntityFramework code first: Set order of fields](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41266992/8601760) might work.

Comment: @aaron Yes, I will report the issue. and no column order doesn't solve the problem. The foreign key property that I want to be at first position is a shadow property - exists only in the change tracker and not in the entity itself.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone wanted a workaround, It's needed to overwrite default foreign key for owned entity, so that we pass property name that would be always at first position in the foreign keys collection:

```
public class InvestmentConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Investment>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Investment> configuration)
    {
        configuration.OwnsOne(typeof(Address), "Address", buildAction => buildAction.HasForeignKey("AInvestmentId"));
    }
}
```

then in DBContext class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new InvestmentConfiguration());
}
```

and the result is:
[image]